# React Native populate user details

Tags: mysql, react-native, laravel-9, php-8

Am trying to populate current logged in user details but am not receiving any data. How do I fix this issue given that this is my controller.

I am populating the user data using JSON using the below method...

```
public function userProfile()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }
```

The populated User details are being passed using Native React as indicated in the method below

`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

        if (!token) {
          console.error('User token not found in AsyncStorage');
          return;
        }

        const response = await fetch('https://dev.myexample.com/api/user-profile', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          const responseData = await response.json();
          setUserData(responseData.user); // Update the user data state with the response
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to fetch user data. Status:', response.status);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, []);`
```

when I submit on my postman am receiving

`{}`

Can someone point me the right direction??

I am expecting to get the user details

EDTT:

Here is my login method in Laravel:

```
public function loginUser(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $validateUser = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validateUser->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Validation error',
                'errors' => $validateUser->errors(),
            ], 401);
        }

        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']))) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Email & Password do not match our records.',
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = auth()->user();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'User Logged In Successfully',
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken,
        ], 200);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $th->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move the fetchUserData method out of the useEffect hook as it is executed once the component mount of which the user details may not be ready because of the async await.

```
      const fetchUserData = async () => {
          try {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    
            if (!token) {
              console.error('User token not found in AsyncStorage');
              return;
            }
    
            const response = await fetch('https://dev.myexample.com/api/user-profile', {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
              },
            });
    
            if (response.ok) {
              const responseData = await response.json();
              setUserData(responseData.user); // Update the user data state with the response
            } else {
              console.error('Failed to fetch user data. Status:', response.status);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
          }
        };

       useEffect(() => {
          fetchUserData();
       }, [userData]);
```